# JavaSQL Exception Cannot Continue Parse

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

I have a requirement to have a SQL statement to do the following:

I have two columns A,B. 
A contains:

```
1
2
3 
4
```

B contains comma separated string in one entry:

```
5,6,7
8,9,0
```

The goal is to have one single SQL query to have o/p like

```
1,5
1,6
1,7
2,8
2,9
```

and so on.

I have a working SQLquery which works fine on Oracle 10g and 11g. But the end goal is to execute the query on a CSV file using a SQL Text Driver. The working query on Oracle DB:

```
select * from (select distinct A as resource, 
(regexp_substr(B, '[^,]+', 1, level)) as ent from tablename
connect by regexp_substr(B , '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null) where ent is not null
```

When I run the command on the CSV, I just get an error "Syntax Error:Can't continue parse"

I am using a third party tool where the object collects data from the CSV file and displays in the UI. All other queries seem to work fine but not this.

Comment: regexp_substr is not standard sql command. And your sql engine/connection for csv file does not support that command.

Comment: Looks that way. Hence I am looking for alternatives.

Comment: Anyone with any other thoughts please?